# Hyperref ruins formulas in Lyx 2.1

Tags: hyperref, lyx, windows, hebrew

I am writing lecture notes in LyX 2.1 on Windows and I have recently enabled `hyperref` in document settings and since then I get strange crossed L marks before every formula I put, e.g.:

[image]

Anybody knows how can I solve it? Maybe I'm missing a crucial package?

**EDIT:** The mwe is available at http://textuploader.com/onny

and on TeX format:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\begin{document}
\global\long\def\difrac#1#2{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\global\long\def\l{\ell}
\subsection{Hyperbolic equations without humuganous conditions}
Take a look at the equations of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
u_{tt} & = & a^{2}u_{xx}+g\left(x,t\right),\quad0<x<\l,t>0\\
u\left(x,t\right)\bigg|_{t=0} & = & f\left(x\right)\\
\difrac{u\left(x,t\right)}t\bigg|_{t=0} & = & F\left(x\right)\nonumber \\
u\left(0,t\right) & = & \mu_{1}\left(t\right)\\
u\left(\ell,t\right) & = & \mu_{2}\left(t\right)\nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}
Use the method from $\left(4.28\right)$on $\nu\left(x,t\right)$
\[
v\left(x,t\right)=A\left(t\right)x+B\left(t\right)
\]
\[
\begin{cases}
v\left(0,t\right)=B\left(t\right)=\mu_{1}\left(t\right)\\
v\left(\l,t\right)=\l A\left(t\right)+B\left(t\right)=\mu_{2}\left(t\right) & \Rightarrow A\left(t\right)=\frac{\mu_{2}\left(t\right)B\left(t\right)}{\l}
\end{cases}
\]
\begin{equation}
v\left(x,t\right)=\frac{x}{\l}\left[\mu_{2}\left(t\right)-\mu_{1}\left(t\right)\right]+\mu_{1}\left(t\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE. You can create this in LyX, save and then open the document using a text editor. Paste that content as your MWE. Please make sure compression is not enabled when saving.

Comment: Yes please provide a .lyx MWE: wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample . Also, if the issue you see is only there when using Hebrew, this is important to know.

Comment: I uploaded a MWE in English. Hebrew seems to be (allegedly) irrelevant.

Comment: @DanisFischer the Hebrew is relevant. I can reproduce the problem you see. If I then select all and then go to Edit > Language and click on English (even if there is already a check), the problem goes away for me.

Comment: I recommend you also upload a .tex minimal example (please put it directly in your question for archival purposes). There are a lot of people around here who don't use LyX. To do that go to File > Export and then choose the format that you use to compile.

Comment: The hebrew seems to be the problem. I could not compile the MWE without error because of missing fonts. However, when I reset the language to English, it compiles as expected with no l-bar. What happens if you set the language to English for the equations? I set Hebrew using XeLaTeX so the issues might be different. I've a vague memory of needing to place ligatures in English at the start of lists, or similar to avoid issues with Hebrew text at the start of the paragraph.

Comment: @penguinprefereed, But I'm writing the lecture notes for hebrew speakers so How can I put in one hit all the equations in 40 pages to english?@scottkosty done.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the macro `\l` and simply write `\ell` everywhere instead of `\l`?

Comment: It changes nothing.

Comment: since hebrew is the trigger, i'd look for a command (possibly a one-letter command, `\L` still looks suspicious) that is defined by both `hyperref` and the hebrew support mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

`hyperref` together with Hebrew and `pdftex` has never [worked properly](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2012/10/07/hebrew-support-in-hyperref-situation-review/). However, recently I had success with modern versions of XeTeX in which `hyperref` and Hebrew do work together.

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-an-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/) to set LyX to typeset Hebrew using XeTeX.